# Nao Robot: How to use the ALImage ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, nao-robot

**What I want to do:**

Convert a ROI of the Nao Robot camera image on the OpenCV::Mat format. Later I will make use of this OpenCV::Mat

**The situation:**

Nao SDK provide the image in a format called [ALImage](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/ref/libalvision/classAL_1_1ALImage.html). It is possible to [convert the ALImage to OpenCV::Mat format](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/cpp/examples/vision/getimage/getimage.html?highlight=alimage), but I do not need all the image, only a small ROI. Despite ALImage provides its own [ROI](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/ref/libalvision/structAL_1_1ALImage_1_1ROI.html), the methods to use it are not really helpful:

```
int        getNumOfROIs () const 
const ROI* getROI (int index) const
void       addROI (const ROI &rect)
void       cleanROIs ()
void       setEnableROIs (bool enable)
bool       isROIEnabled () const
```

**The question:**

How can I use these ROIs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the coordinates of your ROI, you can crop your `cv::Mat` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268062/2098939):

```
// your source image
cv::Mat image(imagesource); 

// a rectangle with your ROI coordinates
cv::Rect myROI(10, 10, 100, 100);

// a "reference" to the image data within the rectangle
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);
```

Note that this does **not** copy the image data. Both, `image` and `croppedImage` share the same underlying raw data (a detailed example can be found in the [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management)). When you're done with the big source image, you can do `image.release()` and `croppedImage = croppedImage.clone();` to deallocate all unnecessary data (outside of your ROI).

**EDIT:**

I didn't work with `AL::ALImage::ROI` yet, but [the definition in alimage/alimage.h](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/ref/libalvision/alimage_8h_source.html) looks familiar to `cv::Rect`. So you can probably do the following:

```
// let's pretend you already got your image ...
AL::ALImage yourImage;
// ... and a ROI ...
AL::ALImage::ROI yourROI;
// ... as well as a Mat header with the dimensions and type of yourImage
cv::Mat header;

// then you can convert the ROI, ...
cv::Rect cvROI(yourROI.x, yourROI.y, yourROI.w, yourROI.h);
// ... wrap ALImage to a Mat (which should not copy anything) ...
header.data = yourImage.getData();
// ... and then proceed with the steps mentioned above to crop your Mat
cv::Mat cropped = header(cvROI);
header.release();
cropped = cropped.clone();

// ... 
// your image processing using cropped
// ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not asking how to use an OpenCV ROI, I am asking how to use the ALImage ROI. Please, read more carefully all the question.

Comment: @Manuel Then please be a little more specific in what you have and what you actually want, because 'use the ALImage ROI' is pretty abstract.