# How to crop image using eye points in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

- I have an image with an eye and points around the eye. For example 10 points. Now I want to crop that eye part.
- But I don't know how can I do it. 
  Please give me an idea.

Comment: The same as you would for any set of points. Bounding rectangle, then crop to that rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you find a "bounding box" from the points you want to crop around. Then, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268062/865719) to crop the image.

Here's a sample code that should give you an idea on what to do:

```
// let's assume that you stored your 10 points in a QList
QList<QpointF> points;
// fill in "points"...
// generate a "bounding box" by finding the min/max in the x and y directions
const auto compareX = [] (const QpointF& p1, const QpointF& p2) {
    return p1.x() < p2.x();
};
const auto compareY = [] (const QpointF& p1, const QpointF& p2) {
    return p1.y() < p2.y();
};
const auto pMinX = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), compareX);
const auto pMaxX = std::max_element(points.begin(), points.end(), compareX);
const auto pMinY = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), compareY);
const auto pMaxY = std::max_element(points.begin(), points.end(), compareY);
cv::Rect boundingBox(pMinX->x(),
                     pMinY->y(),
                     pMaxX->x() - pMinX->x(),
                     pMaxY->y() - pMinY->y());
// get a view on the sub-image
cv::Mat croppedImage = originalImage(boundingBox);
```

Comment: I have stored points in QList<QpointF>.

Comment: It's about the same thing. Check out the edited code.

Comment: @865719.Do you know hot to convert QPointF to Point?

Comment: @SagarPatel: it's really simple just copy `x` and `y`. e.g. `cv::Point newPoint(qPoint.x(), qPoint.y());`

Comment: @SagarPatel If what I've posted solves your problem, consider marking it as a solution.

Comment: @865719.Thanks.It works for me.

Comment: @865719-Can u plz tell me how to enable c++11 in eclipse Luna.Because auto is not working currently.It's showing compareX does not name a type.

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to your C++ compiler flags (I assume that you're using gcc or clang)