# Crop Image from all sides after edge detection

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCV. I want to extract the main object from an image. So, I have applied Canny on the image to get the edges around the main object and got the following output :
[image]

Here is the code to get this using OpenCV in Python:

```
img = cv2.imread(file)
cv2.imshow("orig", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
img = cv2.blur(img,(2,2))
gray_seg = cv2.Canny(img, 0, 50)
```

Now, I want to have the below image as the final output after getting only the main object in the image :
[image]

I want to do it in an optimized manner because I have to process more that 2.5 million images.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would presume your canny returns you a matrix of magnitudes. Just set a threshold and find the left-most, right-most, top-most, and bottom-most pixel crossing the threshold and cut along vertical and horizontal lines going through found points.

Comment: 25 lakhs = 2.5 million?

Comment: Do you require this to be done with OpenCV, or would an [ImageJ](http://imagej.net/) script do as well?

Comment: @JanEglinger This has to be done using OpenCV

Comment: @TomaszKaminski Can you please explain how the image will be cut along those horizontal and vertical lines?

Comment: Just get the `boundingRect` of the edge mask, and slice the image accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

As you have found `clean canny edge`, then to crop the rectangle region, you should calculate the `rectangle boundary`.

The steps:

[image]

The result:

[image]

---

To calculate the canny region boundary, you can just find no-zero points, then get the `min-max coords`. Easy to realize using NumPy. Then crop using slice-op.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.20 15:18:36 CST

#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.20 15:18:36 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np
#img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img = cv2.imread("img02.png")
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200)

## find the non-zero min-max coords of canny
pts = np.argwhere(canny>0)
y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)

## crop the region
cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)

tagged = cv2.rectangle(img.copy(), (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("tagged", tagged)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Of course, do `boundingRect` on the points works too.

Answer (score 1):

The rect function should provide the functionality you need. An example of how to use it can be seen below.

```
cv::Mat image(img);
cv::Rect myROI(posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY);   
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);
```

This is writing in c++ but should be able to find a python equivalent.

The link below my provide more info
[How to crop a CvMat in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267191/how-to-crop-a-cvmat-in-opencv)

Comment: Please note that you will need to convert the image to a matrix to use this function