# Why does converting two images to black and white produce two different results?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

Im trying to do a small project on machine learning and in the process of doing so I have to convert a few images into black and white to classify the images. My problem is that the same method produces wildly different results with the same algorithm.
Here is the image before it is converted [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olTGo.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8yv8.png) is what it looks like after its been converted. Yeah that works fine looks okay.

This is the code that I used.

```py
test_img=Image.open(str(idx) + '.png')
test_img=test_img.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
test_img.show()
test_img=test_img.convert('1')
```

Now I will ty to do the same with this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ZbI.png) which produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBaCo.png) result. As you can see aster it is converted I have weird black spots all over the image. 
This is the code that I used:

```py
source_img=source_img.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
source_img=source_img.convert('1')
source_img.show()
```

Ive tried multiple methods to convert an image to black and white including the `source_img.convert('L')` method and with other methods I'm not able to flatten the image out into a 1D array.

Does anyone know why the conversion works for the first image but not the second?

Comment: Why is your question tagged with OpenCV if you're not using it?

Comment: Are you sure about bw/1bit? Most ML algs work on grayscale, e.g. with 8 bit depth. The reasoning might be indicated in alexanders answer: hard to keep lots of original information with only 1 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PIL method `convert("1")` converts to black and white using dithering, as [the docs state](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

> The default method of converting a greyscale (“L”) or “RGB” image into a bilevel (mode “1”) image uses Floyd-Steinberg dither to approximate the original image luminosity levels.

Dithering replicates many colors with fewer by placing noise within the image to approximate the many colors. Check the [Wikipedia article for dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) for more. For e.g., from that page, the following image is dithered---there's only black and white pixels, but the dithering makes it look grayscale somewhat. This is why your second image has some stippling---the color is not-quite-white, so it tries to approximate the gray with a few specks of black. Not particularly convincing there, though it is more impressive on other types of images:

[image: Dithered image]

If you want to binarize the image, the simplest way is to set a threshold, so that every pixel above that threshold is considered white, and everything below, black. As the docs for `convert()` state:

> If dither is NONE, all non-zero values are set to 255 (white). To use other thresholds, use the `point()` method.

Which you can find the docs for [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point). If you want to use OpenCV, you can accomplish this through `cv2.threshold()`, docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57), tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d8e/tutorial_threshold.html), and a related previous Stack Overflow answer I've given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384019/5087436).