# Detect "dirty borders/lines" in images

Tags: image, numpy, python-imaging-library, border

I'm working on a project and I thought a nice addition would be able to detect these "dirty lines/borders" and alert the user if they have not properly dealt with them.

Example of these borders

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVUve.png]

[image]

I've been googling it this morning trying opencv, PIL, and numpy. I've been able to detect edges, but not quite what I want.

I've tried countless things, but none are what I wanted.
This post came close.
[How to detect edge and crop an image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383209/how-to-detect-edge-and-crop-an-image-in-python)

Essentially I'd like detect these dirty lines somehow.

Example of dirty border/clean border
[image]
Clean
[image]

Comment: How do we know which edges you think are *"dirty"*? How will they look when cleaned?

Comment: I will update the original post with cleaned borders