# Crop and show image that i get from Haar Cascade

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I have trained Haar cascade and now i need to work with founded object. How i can crop it from original image and show in new window?(or show multiple window if i found 2 object on image). There is my code (opencv ver 2.4.13):

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    CascadeClassifier trafficLightCascader;
    string Cascade_name = "TrafficLight.xml";

if (!trafficLightCascader.load(Cascade_name))
{
    cout << "Can't load the face feature data" << endl;
    return -1;
}

vector<Rect> trafficLights;

Mat src = imread("6копия.png"); 
CvRect AssignRect = Rect(0, 0, src.cols, src.rows / 2);
Mat srcImage = src(AssignRect);

Mat grayImage(srcImage.rows, srcImage.cols, CV_8UC1);

cvtColor(srcImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(grayImage, grayImage); 

trafficLightCascader.detectMultiScale(grayImage, trafficLights, 1.1, 1, 0, Size(3,3));

for (int i = 0; i < trafficLights.size(); ++i)
{
    rectangle(src, trafficLights[i], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
}

imshow("src", src);
waitKey(0);


return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `trafficLights vector` is holding each rectangle's data of found objects. You just need to take **left&top coordinates, width and height** of each rectangle and you already have them. All you need is cropping each rectangle by creating Mat format of them and showing in different frames.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267191/how-to-crop-a-cvmat-in-opencv) to learn more about cropping.

Here is the code which you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < trafficLights.size(); ++i)
    {   
        Rect crop_found(trafficLights[i].x,trafficLights[i].y, trafficLights[i].width, trafficLights[i].height);

        Mat found(src, crop_found);

        imshow(to_string(i),found);

        rectangle(src, trafficLights[i], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }
```