# How to crop an image with OpenCV in Rust?

Tags: opencv, rust

I am implementing a backend in Rust to run ONNX inferences on images using the [opencv](https://crates.io/crates/opencv) crate. Everything's working great but I have some doubts about a function I have written to crop an image at a specified location:

```
// assume coordinates are always valid
img
.col_range(&opencv::core::Range::new(xmin, xmax).unwrap()).unwrap()
.row_range(&opencv::core::Range::new(ymin, ymax).unwrap()).unwrap();
```

Is this the only way to accomplish a simple Mat crop? Hope I am not missing a better and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing inefficient with what you've written. OpenCV `Mat`s use data-sharing by default so there's no worry that you're needlessly copying large portions of original image. There's many ways to "slice and dice" the data and what you've chosen is a sensible way to crop an image. In fact, its the primary way you would do this in other languages (from [Cropping an Image using OpenCV](https://learnopencv.com/cropping-an-image-using-opencv/)):

- Python: `cropped_image = img[80:280, 150:330]`
- C++: `Mat cropped_image = img(Range(80,280), Range(150,330));`

What I would recommend, which may be more clear and direct in Rust, is to use [`Mat::roi`](https://docs.rs/opencv/latest/opencv/core/struct.Mat.html#method.roi) (a.k.a. the "region of interest" constructor):

```
let cropped_image = Mat::roi(&img, opencv::core::Rect {
    x: xmin,
    y: ymin,
    width: xmax - xmin,
    height: ymax - ymin,
}).unwrap();
```

See also:

- [How to crop a CvMat in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267191/how-to-crop-a-cvmat-in-opencv)
- [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)